# Как можно сделать такой элемент на CSS

Tags: css

[image: круг]

Как можно сделать такое силами CSS ?

Comment: http://www.sitehere.ru/potryasayushhie-effekty-css3-pri-navedenii можешь тут подглядеть что-нибудь :) там анимации, но их убрать думаю не проблема )

Comment: @SultanovShamil там не совсем тот эффекты, что на изображении

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1747905/909a4d93-42a7-4880-b742-211dd769a8c7/s1200?webp=false);
  background-size: cover;
}

#div2 {
  margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1747905/909a4d93-42a7-4880-b742-211dd769a8c7/s1200?webp=false);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 15px 20px 7px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: забыл про тень))

Comment: ну кто минусует правильный ответ?  )))  детский сад

Comment: А кто сказал, что ответ правильный?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну и что там не правильно?

Comment: @АлексейШимански,  По сути и у автора темы не верно, так-как повтор фона не смотрится вообще должным образом.